# omniauth-facebook 1.5.1 Invalid Credentials

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth

I used

```
gem 'devise',3.2.2
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

and I set

Application.config.session_store :active_record_store

but when I

`link_to "Sign in with #{provider.to_s.titleize}", omniauth_authorize_path(resource_name, provider)`

**I can see a user create in my console but I didn't sign in**

means when I go to the /users/sign_in still need to login

general speaking after I logging in I cannot enter this page

anyone has idea about this??

here is my logs

```
2013-12-19T04:23:02.188900+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 36.224.98.12 at 2013-12-19 04:23:02 +0000
2013-12-19T04:23:02.188900+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/facebook" for 36.224.98.12 at 2013-12-19 04:23:02 +0000
2013-12-19T04:23:02.189529+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-19T04:23:02.189423 #2]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Request phase initiated.
2013-12-19T04:23:03.499973+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBtPAD_sAkIgNKC4VAW8pTE_iTup_Ju-tS1mMBBZ64p1v9PD4liRLZS_Rekah8SqSgvugNTLwxfJqWLOCC_V1m4E4-dhF-wBxSNemax-4X-tH6i-NJ7A7E3JWD51mHA7P8nAoc-o1_NCbgDujac7_WPLzfLFe_tBrVvs-9t2vuSHIS-o0D0ucBiG6cq1wkZL7Buo9qj_yzmlYJgG6jUoWsHDwD3OOgKJ_UWITFBzHqwfymub7h3eZLQmEBzQm2_LOwOFWQoKr3woHyeqd13C1tGjY9xW4yGGkx9SMHJmXNsEDXBFg_c1x-TD4sJqWaQRbQ&state=6335570328a1baae2059bb04ecd91a4e3c66646cb1c88acc" for 36.224.98.12 at 2013-12-19 04:23:03 +0000
2013-12-19T04:23:03.499973+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/users/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBtPAD_sAkIgNKC4VAW8pTE_iTup_Ju-tS1mMBBZ64p1v9PD4liRLZS_Rekah8SqSgvugNTLwxfJqWLOCC_V1m4E4-dhF-wBxSNemax-4X-tH6i-NJ7A7E3JWD51mHA7P8nAoc-o1_NCbgDujac7_WPLzfLFe_tBrVvs-9t2vuSHIS-o0D0ucBiG6cq1wkZL7Buo9qj_yzmlYJgG6jUoWsHDwD3OOgKJ_UWITFBzHqwfymub7h3eZLQmEBzQm2_LOwOFWQoKr3woHyeqd13C1tGjY9xW4yGGkx9SMHJmXNsEDXBFg_c1x-TD4sJqWaQRbQ&state=6335570328a1baae2059bb04ecd91a4e3c66646cb1c88acc" for 36.224.98.12 at 2013-12-19 04:23:03 +0000
2013-12-19T04:23:03.501144+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2013-12-19T04:23:03.501033 #2]  INFO -- omniauth: (facebook) Callback phase initiated.
2013-12-19T04:23:03.711366+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
2013-12-19T04:23:03.711366+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook as HTML
2013-12-19T04:23:03.711366+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQBtPAD_sAkIgNKC4VAW8pTE_iTup_Ju-tS1mMBBZ64p1v9PD4liRLZS_Rekah8SqSgvugNTLwxfJqWLOCC_V1m4E4-dhF-wBxSNemax-4X-tH6i-NJ7A7E3JWD51mHA7P8nAoc-o1_NCbgDujac7_WPLzfLFe_tBrVvs-9t2vuSHIS-o0D0ucBiG6cq1wkZL7Buo9qj_yzmlYJgG6jUoWsHDwD3OOgKJ_UWITFBzHqwfymub7h3eZLQmEBzQm2_LOwOFWQoKr3woHyeqd13C1tGjY9xW4yGGkx9SMHJmXNsEDXBFg_c1x-TD4sJqWaQRbQ", "state"=>"6335570328a1baae2059bb04ecd91a4e3c66646cb1c88acc"}
2013-12-19T04:23:03.711366+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"code"=>"AQBtPAD_sAkIgNKC4VAW8pTE_iTup_Ju-tS1mMBBZ64p1v9PD4liRLZS_Rekah8SqSgvugNTLwxfJqWLOCC_V1m4E4-dhF-wBxSNemax-4X-tH6i-NJ7A7E3JWD51mHA7P8nAoc-o1_NCbgDujac7_WPLzfLFe_tBrVvs-9t2vuSHIS-o0D0ucBiG6cq1wkZL7Buo9qj_yzmlYJgG6jUoWsHDwD3OOgKJ_UWITFBzHqwfymub7h3eZLQmEBzQm2_LOwOFWQoKr3woHyeqd13C1tGjY9xW4yGGkx9SMHJmXNsEDXBFg_c1x-TD4sJqWaQRbQ", "state"=>"6335570328a1baae2059bb04ecd91a4e3c66646cb1c88acc"}
2013-12-19T04:23:03.793802+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://loveturtle.herokuapp.com/
2013-12-19T04:23:03.793802+00:00 app[web.1]: Redirected to http://loveturtle.herokuapp.com/
2013-12-19T04:23:03.794216+00:00 app[web.1]: [deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.
2013-12-19T04:23:03.861590+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 150ms (ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)
2013-12-19T04:23:03.861590+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 302 Found in 150ms (ActiveRecord: 11.4ms)
2013-12-19T04:23:04.105836+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by TurtlesController#sell_index as HTML
2013-12-19T04:23:04.102915+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/" for 36.224.98.12 at 2013-12-19 04:23:04 +0000
```

and my action

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
  # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
  @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

  if @user.persisted?
    sign_in_and_redirect root_path, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
   set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
 else
   session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
   redirect_to root_path
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: I think you are not providing enough context information for anyone to help you. I would like to point you to an article that might help you: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: thx, I have add some supplement, and I will try debugger

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it
after I changed these gem's version

```
   Using devise (3.1.1)
   Using oauth2 (0.8.1)
   Using omniauth (1.1.4)
   Using omniauth-oauth2 (1.1.1)
   Using omniauth-facebook (1.4.1)
```